# Pre-Booking VS At the stations

Tags: bookings, eurail

This questions comes after sifting through existing questions on the topic. Our itinerary in Europe (for July / August) will be: Amsterdam > Brussels > Paris > Munich > Prague > Hamburg > Copenhagen.

We have a Eurail Global Pass.

Our dates are predefined, however, since we're travelling with a baby, I'm wondering if we can get reservations at the counter instead of making bookings in advance. The former option will allow us to choose the hour of the day.

I read on the forum here that on some routes, there is a risk of running into a fully booked train.

Which of these routes are high risk in terms of being fully booked on the day?

Comment: Pretty sure that anything rush hour and/or weekend travel time are those that have the potential to be fully booked. However, you should usually be able to get from A to B, maybe an hour earlier or later with the one notable exception of Hamburg–Copenhagen. *Book that one in advance!* (Caveat: I’m not sure about the French part of the route)

Comment: All long distance trains fill up in the summer, on top of that there are limited numbers of reservations for the holders of Eurail passes. You might also find that there are fewer trains for the long distance connections than you expect. I would book ahead for July and August, train and hotels (or whatever you use instead.)